# full width background color on a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fullscreen, background-color

I'm using a  1120px css responsive framework responsive or it can act as a fixed grid whenever I  need it.

I have a div inside  the 1120px container div on which I want to apply a full width background color.

The background color of the div's is of course only inside the container div and I want to make it fill the full width of the body element.

Now the problem is that the div is generated automatically by a shortcode so I can not create an outer div and set it to 100% width.

Here is the markup from the shortcode:

```
<div class="toggle-default">
    <div class="toggle">
<div class="toggle_title toggle_active">LINE-UP</div>
<div class="toggle_content" style="display:block;">Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</div>

</div>
    </div>
```

and this css :

```
.toggle{ margin-bottom: 5px; 
clear: both; float: left; 
position: relative;  
width: 100%;                
}
.toggle .toggle_title {
position: relative;
font-size: 112.5%;
font-weight: 700;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 25px;
text-decoration: none;

}
```

and here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/5mn22/)

Now, the problem is that this markup is under a container div which has 1120px width.
   I was thinking to add on **.toggle .toggle_title**  position:absolute; and set a  min- width of 1480px for example but then everything will break.

I'm sure that is a better approach to this kind of issue. 
Can anyone give me some tips on how to make this work?
Thank you!

Comment: Using http://www.jsfiddle.net to actually show what's going on will help you get more answers.

Comment: Would you not prefer to set the background color to the `body` element?

Comment: Which div do you want to apply the background color to?

Comment: @Diodeus I don;t want to take to full width of their element, I want to take the full width of the body element;

Comment: @pzin I cannot put it on the body because I want to have different background colors on each div

Comment: I've updated my post with a jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a really ugly way to do this. and I'm posting this with an expectation of someone downvoting this... but it works.

Here's a fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/5mn22/8/

Add this to your CSS:

```
.toggle_title, .toggle_content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

.toggle:before {
    content:"";  
    width:4000px;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    left:-50%;
    z-index:1
}
```

Basically, just adding a null content before the div with a width double the size of expected screen resolution and position it to the left 50% to make sure it stretches the entire distance.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't care about semantics when it's about styling an element, and this is working but is this working on all major browsers ?

Comment: :before and :after work on anything with CSS2+ http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and z-index works with all major browsers.  You just can't z-index:inherit with ie7 - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Thank you! Now a small question: how about when I have different background for the elements using :nth-child() property the first toggle will have red background the second one blue and so on...

Comment: toggling is conditional, so you would have to use something like jQuery - also :nth-child() is not supported on browsers that view anything CSS2 and below.  You will have to give each element it's own ID or Class and color those classes in CSS

Answer (score 2):

Try out thinking different changing css parameter instead of using `background-color`. I have tested it with `:box-shadow` parametr:

```
.toggle {
      box-shadow: -10vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -28vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -42vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -30vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -46vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -15vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42;
      -webkit-box-shadow: -10vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -28vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -42vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -30vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -46vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -15vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42;
      -moz-box-shadow: -10vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -28vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -42vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -30vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -46vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -15vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42;
}
```

Take a look at live example (blue row)^http://kreditka.testovi-site.pw

Regards,
Max